# How do I know which HomeBrew Python 3 Interpreter (Mac, Mavericks) to choose in PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, osx-mavericks, homebrew, pycharm

I'm a Django/Python newbie (although I've done a lot elsewhere).

For various reasons (e.g trying to fool around with Heroku) I decided to uninstall my Python 2.x and 3.x on my Mac (running Mavericks) and replace with a HomeBrew installation.

I know very little about all this, but followed the HomeBrew directions.

When I want to choose a Python interpreter in PyCharm I'm confronted with a bewildering number (3.3, 3.3m, 3.3-32, etc --

[image: Pycharm Interpreter choices])

— have I done something wrong in the installation?  Which interpreter should I choose?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are tied to a specific version (e.g. 3.4), choose `/usr/local/bin/python2` or `/usr/local/bin/python3` depending on which major version you need.

`python2` and `python3` are symlinks to the most recent (or preferred) 2.x/3.x version installed; `python` is a symlink to the default interpreter, which usually is `python2`, but could be `python3`, depending on the system.

The `python2`/`python3` distinction is necessary because Python 3 introduces major changes in syntax and semantics, making a Python 2 script potentially fail.

Comment: Thanks.  Just out of curiosity's sake, what are the others (I understand 3.3, 3.4, but 3.3m? 3.3-32?)

Comment: They must be other (non standard) symlinks to specific versions, just issue `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` to know what they are pointing to (or whether they are hardlinks).